# Deploying an application with Application Parameters through FabricClient

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am currently deploying multiple application instances through the `FabricClient`. A simple implementation of this would be:

```
var appDesc = new ApplicationDescription(new Uri(appName), appType, appVersion);
await fabricClient.ApplicationManager.CreateApplicationAsync(appDesc);
```

Whenever this code is executed the new application is started with its default parameters. It is possible to add name value pairs to the `ApplicationDescription` through its constructor. I would prefer to use the ApplicationParameters.xml files however. Is there a way to specify the new application to use an ApplicationParameters.xml file for its parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the application with the  [`ApplicationDescription(Uri, String, String, NameValueCollection)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.description.applicationdescription.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#System_Fabric_Description_ApplicationDescription__ctor_System_Uri_System_String_System_String_System_Collections_Specialized_NameValueCollection_) overload.

The last parameter is the list of parameters passed to the application.

Comment: That is also described in my question. My question is, however, is it possible to use the ApplicationParameters.xml files instead of a NameValueCollection (or an easy way to obtain a NameValueCollection from the xml files?).

Comment: Sorry, didn't pay attention to this detail, but the fact is that the parameters must be passed by you, so you have to load the file and convert to a key value pair

Comment: How could I find the parameter files? The application parameter file is in a different project (it is a different application type). Perhaps by copying the file to the data package of the service? This would however mean that I have to maintain two parameter files.

Comment: Does it have to be in a parameter file? The file is just convenience to facilitate the deployment, you could store it in a database, in an Configuration Service and so on.